# system logging in linux

Tags: linux, security, logging, syslog

Which one is better? syslog-ng or rsyslog or dsyslog?  Please help me

Comment: This question is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Better how?  Do you have any specific requirements?

Comment: rsyslog :-) just adding to the options list

Comment: This is off topic for serverfault too...

Answer (score 1):

Use the one that came preinstalled, unless you know that you require specific advanced features.

If you require advanced features (automatic rotation, different backends, dynamically-named logfiles per remote logging host), syslog-ng will be a good starting point.